# htaccess rewriterule with order in url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to put together a rewrite rule for an Apache server.  It should take 'order/###' and change it to 'order.php?id=###'.  For some reason it's rewriting as 'order.php/###'.  If I change it to anything other than 'order' my rule works fine.

Anyone know what's going on?

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

## tighten host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .? http://mydomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

## Dynamic Pages
RewriteRule ^order/([0-9]+)/?$ order.php?code=$1 [L,NC]

## Static Page Redirects
RewriteRule ^prices$ /prices.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^examples$ /examples.php [L,NC]
```

I have no access to the httpd main server config file on the live server.

I'm using a wamp server for local development.

Comment: I can't see how these rules as posted could cause that. Do you have any additional rules in your .htaccess? And are you seeing it actually redirect the browser to `/order.php/123` ?

Comment: That should work, try changing the first `[L,NC]` to `[R]` and check what the link is. It should be correct.

Comment: That's what I'm seeing in the browser.  It's not redirecting when I change it to a redirect.  It doesn't look like it's even hitting my rule.  I can't seem to find what it is hitting though.  I'm using a wamp server.